# How to keep focus in same text field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and I'm writing an app using Angular, in which user would
enter several codes to be sent to the server.
User will enter the code and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to send it to server.
I need to keep focus on the field, so that he can enter next code.
the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is working fine, but when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it loses focus.

My HTML code is like this:

```
<body ng-app="POT">
    <br/>
    <div ng-controller="RecordPotController" align="center">
        <div><b>{{hello}}</b>

        </div>
        <br/>
        <form ng-submit="do_record_pot()">
            <table width='400'>
                <tr>
                    <td>POT Code:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="myFocus" focus-on="focusMe" type="text" ng-model="keywords" ng-blur="do_record_pot()" placeholder="Enter POT code" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
<pre ng-model="result">
result: {{result}}<br/>
message: {{msg}}<br/>
status: {{status}}<br/>
</pre>

    </div>
</body>
```

And my JS code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("POT", []);

app.directive('focusOn', function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.$on('focusOn', function (e, name) {
            if (name === attr.focusOn) {
                elem[0].focus();
            }
        });
    };
});

app.factory('focus', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return function (name) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('focusOn', name);
        });
    }
});

app.controller("RecordPotController", function ($scope, focus) {
    focus('focusMe');
    $scope.hello = "Enter POT code and press Tab key";

    $scope.do_record_pot = function () {
        $scope.result = "POT recorded: " + $scope.keywords;
        $scope.msg = "now enter next code";
        $scope.keywords = "";
        $scope.status = 123;
    };

});
```

I created a fiddle to show the example -

http://jsfiddle.net/patildg/LN4J8/67/

How should I keep the focus in that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using ngKeydown? It might be more appropriate in this situation.

HTML:

```
<input id="myFocus" type="text" ng-model="keywords" placeholder="Enter POT code" ng-keydown="keyDown($event)" />
```

JS:

```
app.controller("RecordPotController", function ($scope) {
    var do_record_pot = function () {
        $scope.result = "POT recorded: " + $scope.keywords;
        $scope.msg = "now enter next code";
        $scope.keywords = "";
        $scope.status = 123;
    };

    $scope.hello = "Enter POT code and press Tab key";

    $scope.keyDown = function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 13) {
            do_record_pot();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gxh5U/1/

Comment: yes, that works, with small change on do_record_pot() add $scope. Also, your fiddle is not matching with this code above?

Comment: Ah, sorry about the fiddle link, I forgot to save! It's been updated. You could add do_record_pot() to $scope, but since it's only being used within the controller definition, there's no need (unless you plan on using it elsewhere!)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('noTab', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope,$element) {
            $element.on("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                if(event.which === 9) { 
                  event.preventDefault();
                }

            });
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LN4J8/68/